# How to tell typescript that the values of different variables are related?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

Is there a way to tell TypeScript that if one variable has one value, then it's impossible for another variable to have another value?

For example, having `--strictNullChecks` enabled and having two variables `isLoading: boolean` and `data: Data | null`. If `isLoading = true`, then `data` is never gonna be `null` but TypeScript doesn't know that and gives an error when wanting to use `data`:

```
if (isLoading) {
  return;
}

useData(data);  // error data might be null
```

I guess I could also check for `isLoading && data != null` but it feels redundant and looks a lot like defensive programming, both bad smells that I wouldn't have to face if I was using regular JavaScript.

Another scenario:

```
type: 'demo' | 'final' | 'alternative' | null;
data: Data | null;
isLoading: boolean;

startProcess(type: 'demo' | 'final', data: Data) => void;
```

If I do the following, TypeScript is also gonna complain:

```
if (isLoading) {
  return;
}

if (type !== 'alternative') {
  startProcess(type, data);  // Type 'null' is not assignable to type '"demo" | "final"'.'"demo" | "final"'.
}
```

However, I know for sure, that if `type != alternative` and `isLoading = false`, then, `type` is not gonna be `null`.

I would also like to avoid using `!` if I can tell the type system how to better reason as the `!` operator can eventually silence proper errors.

Here's also a codesandbox with what I tried: https://codesandbox.io/s/sweet-williamson-7bs9d

It also looks a bit like a bug in TypeScript because if I don't destructure the `input` argument and instead use it directly with dot notation, it works.

Answer (score -1):

I had similar questions when I started TypeScript. It felt a little bit restrictive. But then I realized that this is exactly where errors happen: when you think "I'm sure that if a=null then this and that is impossible". First of all, how sure can you be really? There are aleays those edge-cases as we all know. Second, if *you* are sure the code will work this way, it's nevertheless good to let others who might read your code and typescript itself be sure by adding explicit checks and type conversions. So I think an explicit check for `isLoading && data !== null` is a good practice. If in your code however those two conditions are always met/unmet together, it means that the architecture is suboptimal and you could just get rid of `isLoading` and simply check data.

TL;DR You can't do that implicit logic that you want and I consider it to be for the best.

Comment: If you have a look at the provided codesandbox, there's a way of achieving that (look at `altMain`). About `data !== null` and all of that, the problem with defensive programming is that you can silently catch errors that you want to happen, in this case, if I get a `isLoading = false` with `data = null`, I want an error to happen, not just silently go into the `loading...` state.


Finally, I know the example is a bit simple (for the sake of simplicity) so it can be reduced most of the time to check for `data != null`, but the question goes more in the direction of relating two variables.